# Amazon Kinesis Firehose to S3 with Protobuf data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, protocol-buffers, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Has anyone tried pushing [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (PB) data through Kinesis Firehose for storage to S3.  I ask this question because Protobuf is (usually) a binary format, and I recall (perhaps incorrectly) that Firehose runs all data through a base64 conversion before writing.  I will need to read the PB data later for processing and want to know if I would need to de-base64 it before usage, or will I have access to raw PB data straight off S3.  Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question. However, I need to ask why? Google PB is a serialized data format. This means that you are taking structured data, changing its format and then sending it to Kineses Firehose. You would then have to deserialize the data, which may mean recreating the Google libraries. Why not just send the data to Kinesis directly?

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I want to do: write PB straight to S3.  I'm using FH as a buffer to aggregate a number of file-writes over time.  However, from what I have read, FH will not take raw binary data, and will instead convert to base64 in transit.  Am I incorrect about this?  I'd love to just write a PB byte[] straight to FH, and then read it straight off S3 later.

Comment: Here is a reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_Record.html

Comment: The reference says that the BLOB is base64 encoded when it is serialized.

Comment: did you manage to do this using protobufs and firehose eventually?

Comment: No.  It seemed that Firehose was not well suited for binary data.  AMQP worked better for us since it is binary capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass binary data to Kineses Firehose, and Kinesis will base64 encode the data before sending to another AWS Service. Look at the setData() function in the Java documents:

[Kinesis Firehose Record](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/kinesisfirehose/model/Record.html)

You would then need to decode the data for further processing after reading from S3 for example.

Comment: Then, if Kineses Firehose requires that binary data be written in base64 encoding, are there other ways to put unencoded binary data to S3?  Alternatively, I'm starting to think that we will need to implement our own AMPQ or Kafka service to handle data aggregation, followed by direct binary file copying to S3..

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What it tells me is that firehose is not a solution for binary log files!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Lambda to write the binary data directly to S3. You would need to be able to pull the file from your source from the lambda though, since I believe API Gateway will Base64-encode binary payloads.