# AWS Kinesis Firehose Delivery stream sending protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I saw [this SO about Amazon Kinesis Firehose to S3 with Protobuf data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868341/amazon-kinesis-firehose-to-s3-with-protobuf-data), which was asked over 5 years ago.

Just wondering if anything has changed with Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose and whether it can now forward protobuf data without base64 encoding the data?

FYI I'm looking into forwarding OpenTelemetry/OTLP protobuf requests to Elasticsearch using a telemetry pipeline that looks like: `apps (in EKS)` -> `OTEL collector agent` -> `Kinesis Data Stream` -> `Kinesis Delivery Stream` -> `Elastic APM` -> `Elasticsearch`. Note: Elastic APM only supports grpc/proto or http/proto and the binary protobuf data can't be base64 encoded or it wont work.